# Reset filters after new keyword search?

Tags: search

We're using a faceted search to get good results:

Keyword search (on homepage) -> result page -> filter results

**Question**: Should the filters be reset when the user does a new keyword search on the result page?

My thoughts so far:

**Pro**: There's always the possibility that the user just doesn't get that there are still active filters.

**Con**: It's likely that the filters don't change between searches so resetting them would be annoying for the user.

**My approach** would be to not reset them but make it visually as clear as possible that there are active filters. If he goes back to the homepage I think it's clear that the filters have to be reset.

Do you agree? Other thoughts?

---

**Update**: Very rough mockup on how the result page looks (requested by Matt):

[image]

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I've had to beat this topic into the ground with the current product I'm working on.  By what you have have stated, it looks like you're on the right path.  I would not reset the filters automatically, as this could cause a lot of frustration to users.

**Clicking a reset action >  re-entering filter criterion.**

Here are a few tidbits that I have learned along the road that may help:

- If there are multiple fields in the filter or the filter can be hidden include a global reset
- If there is a global reset, have this automatically re-load the data
- If the filter can be hidden, add a global clear that will only clear the fields, and not re-load the data

Additionally, to comment on your "Con"; there are ways to point out that filter criteria have been applied.  Couple this with a reset or clear, and it becomes fairly obvious that the keyword search has been filtered, and that there is an easy way to remove the filter.

Comment: Thanks for the additional hints, I'll go with this solution.

Answer (score 1):

I agree, you should persist the filter settings unless you return to the home page. I have often searched for something on a site and have had to change or refine the search term, where my other requirements have remained the same. For example the other day I was on the Home Depot site searching for axes and axe handles within a certain price range. I ended up finding results from the search terms: axe, log splitter, wedge, axe handle. While searching these terms, my budget requirement remained the same.